# my mapView.apk file execute properly on simuletor application start also but map is not show on the simulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

while the application execute only the mapView back ground and the logo at the given location is appear. the map is not able to visible.

Answer (score 1):

Have You created map API key for your PC? If not get the Map API key from [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html) for your PC and use it in your app. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it happens when :

1. you miss to add the INTERNET permission in manifest.xml
2. you do not have a proper API key.
3. Internet is not working on your simulator.

check these conditions..and if you are using internet behind the proxy , then your AVD cannot load any application that is using the map.